# JPA primary key for MySQL

Tags: mysql, jpa, primary-key, biginteger

I have a table which has the primary key of type BIGINT UNSIGNED. Now, how can I model this key in JPA? If I use java.math.BigInteger, JPA will not accept it.  If I use Long, then the type of JPA seems to be too small in comparison with the type of MySQL. What if the number of records exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Long and sleep at night.  Look at the max value for a long.  If your table ever comes close to that number I'd be surprised.  I know we live in the era of Big Data, but your fears are overblown and unrealistic in the near term.